# “cannot find symbol” while compiling opencv on MacOS10.12

Tags: python, macos, opencv, cmake

Environment:MacOS 10.12, CMake 3.9.0, python 2.7

I try to compile Opencv on mac using this [tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/) When i followed the Step 8

```
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH=~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages \
    -D PYTHON2_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin \
    -D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules ..

$ make -j4
```

I got the following information

```html
/Users/niceycb/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_qtkit.mm:46:9: fatal error: 
      'QTKit/QTKit.h' file not found
#import <QTKit/QTKit.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_qtkit.mm.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 35%] Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_shape.a
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../../lib/libopencv_shape.a(precomp.cpp.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../../lib/libopencv_shape.a(precomp.cpp.o) has no symbols
[ 35%] Built target opencv_shape
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The first error is a known issue(because of QuickTime Kit was deprecated in OS X v10.9,my MacBook version:10.12) and I have followed several solutions but none worked.

I have no idea about the second error, there seems no solution about it.

Comment: Which line describes the first error, and which line - the second one? I see only one error message, lines 1-3 in the log you provide. `has no symbol` is not an error, but informative message. Whole build is terminated because the first error is "fatal".

Comment: So you mean as long as I solve the first error, the whole issue can be solved? :)

Comment: Yes, solving the first error would allows build process to continue. However, "has no symbol" message *may* signal about possible problems in futher building. For the future: when face with errors in build process, rerun `make` **without** `-j` option. Such a way it is easy to detect which error terminates whole build. Also, without `-j` option build log will be more consistent and readable.